# Python classes/functions & self paramter

Tags: python, self

I have some simple code to find the indexes of 2 elements that add up to a sum. (assume sum exists in list)

```
class Solution(object):
    def twoSum(self, nums, target):
        compliment = []
        for ind, item in enumerate(nums):
            print(ind)
            if item in compliment:
                return [nums.index(target - item), ind]
            compliment.append(target - item)
        return [0, 0]

if __name__ == "__main__":

    result = Solution()
    final = result.twoSum([3, 3], 6)

    #Why does this not work without removing the self parameter??
    #final = Solution.twoSum([3, 3], 6)

    print(str(final))
```

I'm trying to learn how to instantiate an object best in Python. In my main function, I thought I'd simplify it by doing it in 1 line instead of 2. You can see my 2 attempts to call the function in this class. The 2nd fails, unless I remove the self parameter from the function parameters. It's because I'm trying to pass 2 instead of 3 arguments.

Anyways, I'm confused why my two implementations are different and why one works and the other doesn't. I'm also not sure I even need self here at all. It seems like self is mostly used when you have `__init__` and are defining variables for the class? Since I'm not doing that here, do I even need it at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `self` parameter is only required (and will only work) for instance methods. Instance methods are also the default type. To use it without an instance, and without the `self` parameter, decorate it as a `staticmethod`:

```
class Solution(object):
    @staticmethod
    def twoSum(nums, target):
        compliment = []
        for ind, item in enumerate(nums):
            print(ind)
            if item in compliment:
                return [nums.index(target - item), ind]
            compliment.append(target - item)
        return [0, 0]

if __name__ == "__main__":

    final = Solution.twoSum([3, 3], 6)
    print(str(final))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can opt to either decorating your function with as a staticmethod or a classmethod in Python. In the case of the classmethod, you would need to have `cls` in the method signature. Here is a good discussion to distinguish the two:

[What is the difference between @staticmethod and @classmethod?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136097/what-is-the-difference-between-staticmethod-and-classmethod)

BTW — for your code, I would **highly** suggest using a set instead of an array. It will make your code much more efficient. Checking if the target value was already seen in a set is a constant time operation on average.

Comment: I ended up using a dictionary instead of a list and it seems better :)